# Prolog find element in list of lists with preference

Tags: list, prolog, find

I have list of lists like:

```
L = [[Q,w,E,],[Q,w,Z,r],[A,s,D,f]]
```

I know the first two and I need to get the rest.
For example I have Q,w and I need to get Z,r or E,r.
I would like to somehow tell that with priority I always want that touple contain Z, but if doesnt exist give me E,r.

I tried:

```
member([Q,w,Z,VB],[[Q,w,E,o],[Q,w,Z,r],[A,s,D,f]]).
```

But that always give me `Z = E, VB = o`

Comment: mind that identifiers starting with a capital letter are variables, not constants. You better use strings...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know the difference in Prolog between an Atom and a Variable, you can read about their syntax [here](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse2)
Now, if you want a list of atoms that begin with an upper-case letter, you must enclose them in single quotes, otherwise prolog will interpret them as variables.
Now if you fix the syntax of your consult, you will get the following result:

```
?- member(['Q',w,Z,VB],[['Q',w,'E',o],['Q',w,'Z',r],['A',s,'D',f]]).

VB = o,
Z = 'E'
VB = r,
Z = 'Z'
false
```

Note how in this case I enclosed in single quote all atoms beginning with an upper-case letter, except for `Z` and `VB` in the first argument of the `member/2` predicate, cause in this case they function as variables to be instanciated by prolog with the atoms needed to complete this case.

Comment: With `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` the second argument reads more compactly `["QwEo","QwZr","AsDf"]`